# How to convert a single-byte const char* to a UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a function which requires me to pass a UTF-8 string pointed by a char*, and I have the char pointer to a single-byte string. How can I convert the string to UTF-8 encoding in C++? Is there any code I can use to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What encoding is your original string?

Comment: pathnames on linux does not enforce a given encoding, The only rule is it can't contain a / . Thus, anyone can create a file name using any encoding, or even a filename that's illegally encoded in any given charset. You could guess that it's ISO8859-1 and transform it with the iconv() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a string to a different character encoding, use any of various character encoding libraries. A popular choice is [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) (the standard on most Linux systems).

However, to do this you first need to figure out the encoding of your input. There is unfortunately no general solution to this. If the input does not specify its encoding (like e.g. web pages generally do), you'll have to guess.

As to your question: You write that you get the string from calling `readdir` on a FAT32 file system. I'm not quite sure, but I believe `readdir` will return the file names as they are stored by the file system. In the case of FAT/FAT32:

- The short file names are encoded in some DOS [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) - which code page depends on how the files where written, there's no way to tell from just the file system AFAIK.
- The long file names are in UTF-16.

If you use the standard `vfat` Linux kernel module to access the FAT32 partition,  you should get long file names from `readdir` (unless a file only has an 8.3 name). <strike>These can be decoded as UTF-16.</strike> FAT32 stores the long file names in UTF-16 internally. The `vfat` driver will convert them to the encoding given by the `iocharset=` mount parameter (with the default being the default system encoding, I believe).

Additional information:

You may have to play with the mount options `codepage` and `iocharset` (see http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount ) to get filenames right on the FAT32 volume. Try to mount such that filenames are shown correctly in a Linux console, then proceed. There is some more explanation here: http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/HowTo/MountFATFileSystems

Comment: The last link solved my specific problem. It was sufficient, it seems, to mount the device with appropriate parameters to get it correctly working. I mark this as the accepted answer as it solved my specific situation and it explains correctly the general case. Thanks to everyone anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Linux, you're looking for [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv_open.3.html). When you open the converter (`iconv_open`), you pass *from* and *to* encoding. If you pass an empty string as *from*, it'll convert from the locale used on your system which should match the file system.

On Windows, you have pretty much the same with [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you pass `CP_ACP` as the codepage. But on Windows you can simply call the Unicode version of the functions to get Unicode straight away and then convert to UTF-8 with [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `CP_UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the top bit is set on the 1 byte string so the function you're passing that to is expecting more than 1 byte to be passed.

First, print the string out in hex.

i.e.

```
unsigned char* str = "your string";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
  printf("[%02x]", str[i]);
```

Now have a read of the wikipedia article on UTF8 encoding which explains it well.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

UTF-8 is variable width where each character can occupy from 1 to 4 bytes.

Therefore, convert the hex to binary and see what the code point is.

i.e. if the first byte starts 11110 (in binary) then it's expecting a 4 byte string.  Since ascii is 7-bit 0-127 the top bit is always zero so there should be only 1 byte.  By the way, the bytes following the first byte in a wide character of a UTF8 string will start "10..." for the top bits.  These are the continuation bytes... that's what your function is complaining about... i.e. the continuation bytes are missing when expected.
So the string is not quite true ascii as you thought it was.

You can convert using as someone suggested iconv, or perhaps this library http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried with the string "/system/mnt/usb0/audio/07 Dracula Der Pfähler.mp3" and I got [2f][73][79][73][74][65][6d][2f][6d][6e][74][2f][75][73][62][30][2f][61][75][64][69][6f][2f][30][37][20][44][72][61][63][75][6c][61][20][44][65][72][20][50][66][e4][68][6c][65][72][2e][6d][70][33]. It seems quite strange as the character ä is part of the ASCII set, and so it should ok. Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Luca - Yes, you're wrong (sorry).  
ASCII English characters (less than 0x80) are identical to their UTF-8 equivalents.  
ä converted to e4 which is not legal UTF-8.

Comment: Ah, I understand! Ok, so UTF-8 is not backward compatible with extended ASCII. This explains why I noticed the problem with both 'è' and 'ä'. Thanks!